# DNS MX Record for Exchange 2013, with Edge server,

Tags: mx-record, exchange-2013, internal-dns

In Exchange 2013, which is set up with both postoffice and edge servers, which should the MX Record in DNS point to?

Both servers are behind a Cisco ASA5510 firewall which has NAT configured to route port 25 traffic to the Edge server, so is it correct that this internal dns MX record is only for internal mail, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Edge Transport server is responsible for receiving email from the internet. Your MX record should designate your Edge Transport server as the authoritative mail server for your public domain name.

You don't need an internal MX record. so I'm not sure why you're referencing that in your question.

Comment: Only because I assume (wrongly?) that the dns servers inside my private domain are only used by hosts on my private subnet, and not by hosts outside on the public internet, that are using dns MX records for my domain on public dns servers, that point to the public IP address of my gate way on my ISP's public subnet. Does this mean I don't need an MX record on my internal dns Server at all?

Comment: Correct. Your internal hosts don't need to resolve the MX record for your Edge Transport server. Have a read here on the DNS aspects of implementing an Edge Transport server - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641596(v=exchg.150).aspx